# del route on kali linux on wsl2

Tags: kali-linux, routing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am kind of new to linux, it has only been about 2 month since I started. So I am having trouble with the route commands.

My problem is that I don't have the same  local IP address on windows that the one I have on wsl.  However I managed to add another route, but is not the one by default, so I am trying to ether del 172.20.128.0 or make 192.168.1.0 the default/main one so that others devices can ping me, and other stuff like that.

ipconfig (on windows)

```
Carte Ethernet vEthernet (WSL) :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . :
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::c181:db91:a200:5517%60
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.20.128.1
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.240.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . :
```

```
Carte réseau sans fil Wi-Fi :

   Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : home
   Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::2143:d5bf:e724:d291%5
   Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.1.33
   Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

route (kali-linux on wsl)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         lelievre-pc.msh 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.20.128.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

ifconfig (kali-linux on wsl)

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.134.143  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.20.143.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feab:4d29  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:ab:4d:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 5898  bytes 1405127 (1.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35  bytes 2414 (2.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ip addr (kali-linux on wsl)

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7e:1c:de:e7:d3:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: dummy0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1a:65:36:61:31:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:ab:4d:29 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.134.143/20 brd 172.20.143.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.1.69/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:feab:4d29/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
```

thanks for reading and trying to help me I have been stuck on this whole ping problem and stuff for about a week

Comment: You'll need to configure on Windows side to make wsl use switch/bridge style networking (could be called "external" or so), assuming it's possible.

Comment: is that with the hyper-V thing ?

Comment: Yes.  WSL2 is running on a virtual network card, which by default is NAT'd.  To have any hope of doing what you are trying to do, you would need the vNIC to be bridged.  See [this post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/hdmspt/using_bridged_networking_to_get_outside_access_to/), but be sure to read the caveat! :-)  For more information, search for *WSL2 bridged*

Comment: thanks I will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really have two questions there -- The one in your title, and then the "real one" hidden in there.

1. How to change routes under WSL2
2. (Real) How to allow other hosts on the network access to the WSL2 instance (e.g. `ping`, etc.)

If your goal is really the second, then I would honestly suggest just ignoring the first one.  WSL2 runs on a virtual network card (vNIC) which, by default, is running NAT'd under the Windows host (through a subset of Hyper-V functionality).  To have any hope of modifying it, you'd need to change it to a bridged interface.  And that's just not a normally supported configuration.  I'll point you to [this information](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/hdmspt/using_bridged_networking_to_get_outside_access_to/) on Reddit about a way to potentially do it, but quote the caveat from that post:

> This is hilariously unsupported, unapproved, and produced by experimentation alone. Provided without warranty or liability. I guarantee only that it works for me so far. May cause stress, hair loss, or alcoholism. Do not taunt.

:-)

Realistically, I'll phrase it another way.  It's *possible* that this could cause near unrecoverable network failure in WSL2, to the point of needing a Windows reinstall.  WSL2 networking appears to be a bit "fragile", and some of the questions I've seen here on Stack regarding failures never seem to end up with a solution, sadly.

But for the real question of how to get access to the WSL2 instance from other machines on the network, I've written up several answers elsewhere on Stack, but never for the Unix/Linux one here.

That said, I'm not going to repeat it all again here, since it's really not a "Linux/Unix" thing, but I'll point you to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1618446/1210833).

Note that if your main goal with Kali Linux is to learn networking (as for a lot of folks I see that use Kali on WSL2), then IMHO WSL2 isn't a great solution for that.  WSL2 is great at a lot of things, but its networking is quite limited since it is running virtualized.

That said, the `socat` solution I offer in that answer is an interesting bit of networking hackery from which you'd likely learn something network related -- I know I did!

Comment: Ok thanks for this answer, I don't want to risk to have to reinstall windows, so I recently ordered a raspberry in order to have a cheap alternative to wsl2 for the local ip part, will it directly be a part of my LAN then?

Comment: Yes, that's a good alternative.  It will run directly with its own physical network (Ethernet or Wifi, whichever you prefer).  And it will be directly accessible from other machines on the network.